# Projection onto unit $\ell_2$ ball in explicit form not projection form

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, projection, gradient-descent

When the gradient of a differentiable scalar-valued function is Lipschitz, i.e.,

$$ \|\nabla f(y) - \nabla f(x)\| \leq L\|y-x\| $$

for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and some $L>0$, then it is well-known that the following holds.

$$ f(y) \leq f(x) + \left\langle \nabla f(x), y - x \right\rangle + \frac{L}{2}\|y-x\|^2, \qquad \forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n $$

It is straightforward to let $y = x - \gamma \nabla f(x)$ and show the following:

$$
f(y)
\leq
f(x)-\gamma \left(1-\frac{\gamma L}{2}\right)\|\nabla f(x)\|^2.
$$

The above shows that letting $0<\gamma \leq \frac{2}{L}$ would decrease the function value unless $\nabla f(x)=0$ where $\nabla f(x)=0$ is the stationary condition.

---

**General case**

Notice $y=x - \gamma \nabla f(x)=P_{\mathbb{R}_n}(x - \gamma \nabla f(x))$ so we can define $y=P_{C}(x - \gamma \nabla f(x))$ where $C$ is any closed convex set, $x \in C$, and $P_{C}$ is the orthogonal projection onto $C$. Then one can write the following:

$$
\begin{aligned}
f(y)
&\leq
f(x)+\frac{1}{\gamma}\langle y-(x-\gamma\nabla f(x)), y-x
\rangle
-(\frac{1}{\gamma}-\frac{L}{2})\|y-x\|^2
\\
&=
f(x)+\frac{1}{\gamma}\langle P_{C}(v)-v, P_{C}(v)-x
\rangle
-(\frac{1}{\gamma}-\frac{L}{2})\|y-x\|^2
\end{aligned}
$$
where $v=x-\gamma\nabla f(x)$.
The above shows we can decrease the function value because the inner product is the variational inequality and is negative.

---

**Question**

Let $C$ be the unit $\ell_2$-ball where the stationary point is either $\nabla f(x)=0$ or $x=\alpha \nabla f(x)$ for some $\alpha \leq 0$. Is it possible to write an equivalent inequality that includes only $x$ and $\nabla f(x)$ not $v$ which does not decrease when $\nabla f(x)=0$ or $x=\alpha \nabla f(x)$?

---

**My try**

When $v \in \bar{B}(0,1)$, then $P_{C}(v)=v$ and we are back in $\mathbb{R}^n$. When $v \notin \bar{B}(0,1)$, then $y=\frac{v}{\|v\|}$ and

$$
\langle P_{C}(v)-v, P_{C}(v)-x
\rangle
=1-\|v\|+(1-\frac{1}{\|v\|})\|x\|^2-\gamma (1-\frac{1}{\|v\|})
\langle
x, \nabla f(x)
\rangle
$$
and
$$
\|y-x\|^2
=
1+\|x\|^2(1-\frac{2}{\|v\|})+\frac{2\gamma}{\|v\|}
\langle
x, \nabla f(x)
\rangle
.
$$

---

**Remark**

The above inequalities are coming from solving $\min_{x \in C} f(x)$ using projected gradient descent where $x_{k+1}=P_C(x_k-\gamma \nabla f(x_k))$. However, here we only do one step. When $C=\mathbb{R}^n$ then $\nabla f(x)=0$. When $C=\bar{B}_2(0,1)$ then $\nabla f(x)=0$ or $x=\alpha \nabla f(x)$ for some negative $\alpha$.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking.

Comment: I am looking for an inequality like $
f(y)
\leq
f(x)-\gamma (1-\frac{\gamma L}{2})\|\nabla f(x)\|^2.
$ which only involves $x$ and $\nabla f(x)$ on the right hand side. When $y$ is defined in terms of projection, I get projections on the right hand side. However, I want things be in explicit form not in projection form when $C$ is a unit $\ell_2$ ball.

Comment: Are you trying to minimise $f$ on $C$?

Comment: Not necessarily. Those inequality are coming from one step of projected gradient descent over $C$. Each step gives us decrease when $C$ is convex. For the special case of $\ell_2$ ball I want things in terms of gradient.

Comment: @copper.hat: I added a remark. Hopefully, it clears what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y = P_C(x-\gamma \nabla f(x))$. Then $y$ is a solution of
$$
\min_y f(x)  +\nabla f(x)(y-x) + \frac1{2\gamma} \|y-x\|^2 + I_C(y),
$$
where $I_C$ is the indicator function of $C$. Then
$$
f(y) \le f(x)  +\nabla f(x)(y-x) + \frac L2 \|y-x\|^2\\
\le \frac L2 \|y-x\|^2 - \frac1{2\gamma} \|y-x\|^2\\
= \frac12(L-\frac1\gamma) \|y-x\|^2.
$$
And the function value decreases if $L< \frac1\gamma$.

Comment: $x$ is in the $\mathbb{R}^n$. In the form you provided, the right hand side is not in terms of the $x$ and gradient. Please remove your post because it does not address my question.

Comment: Huh? If $x$ is not a stationary point then $y \ne x$ and the function values decrease, i.e., $f(y) < f(x)$. I doubt that the estimate with just $\nabla f(x)$ holds for the case with constraints.

Comment: For instance, take $C=\{0\}$, then $y=x$, and the inequality $f(y)\le f(x) - (..) \|\nabla f(x)\|^2$ is only true if $\nabla f(x)=0$.

Comment: @Sepide That is an unreasonable request. Your question is not entirely clear and the above does answer your question. You can compute a closed form for $y$ in terms of $x$ and the gradient for the $C$ in the question.